# How to align text and add vertical lines along the sides of the bars in a coord_polar bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I have the following data set:

```
LDP <- c(6.6, -1.5, 1.7, 90.3, -59.6, -7.1)
var = c("Time", "Age", "RADS", "False", "Biopsy", "Screening")

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(var, LDP))
df$LDP <- as.numeric(df$LDP)
```

| LDP | var |
| --- | --- |
| 6.6 | Time |
| -1.5 | Age |
| 1.7 | RADS |
| 90.3 | False |
| -59.6 | biopsy |
| -7.1 | Screening |

I have created a poolar coord bar graph with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = var, y = LDP, fill = LDP >= 0)) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
                   position = position_dodge(),
                   width = 1) +
          geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
          geom_text(aes(label = LDP), 
                    hjust = 0.5, 
                    vjust = 0.5, 
                    colour = "black", fontface = "bold", 
                    position = position_stack()) +
          coord_polar() +
          theme_minimal() +
          labs(fill = "Status", x = "", y = "") +
          theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

The above command resulted in the graph as shown in first image:

[image: Image 1]

But I wants the text alignment and creating horizontal lines that goes along the sides of each bar exactly the same as in second image:

[image: image 2]
I would be thankful for your kind help.

Regards,
Farhan
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l71Se.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KNLQ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the linked image was created with the geomtextpath package. The code would look something like this:

```r
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = LDP, fill = LDP >= 0)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = position_dodge(),
           width = 1) +
  geom_hline(aes(linetype = "baseline", yintercept = 0)) +
  geom_textpath(aes(label = LDP, vjust = LDP >= 0), 
                hjust = 0.5, 
                colour = "black", fontface = "bold", 
                position = position_stack()) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0:6 + 0.5) +
  coord_curvedpolar() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = "dashed") +
  labs(fill = "Status", x = "", y = "") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = -0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan, Your response was helpful. While the geom_text() values for FALSE should be inside the dashed circle though they are OK for TRUE. How can we go about this?

Comment: @Farhan you can use `vjust` as an aesthetic mapping - see my update.

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem is resolved by your response.